# CocoaPods - [!] The `xcproj` tool has failed to touch the project

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I get the following error when I'm trying to update my pods:

> [!] The `xcproj` tool has failed to touch the project. Check whether
>   your installation of `xcproj` is functional.
>
> xcproj --project "/xxxxx/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj" touch
>   DVTFoundation.framework not found. It probably means that you have
>   deleted, moved or renamed the Xcode copy that compiled `xcproj`.
>   Simply recompiling `xcproj` should fix this problem.

I rebuildet everything and reinstalled CocoaPods and nothing helped.
Does anyone have any suggestions what else I could try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have `xcproj` installed, probably via homebrew, and it breaks when you update versions of Xcode. Like the error message states, you need to reinstall it. You should be able to do this with:

```
brew reinstall xcproj
```